# Asp.net using ajax (javascript) to get data from api controller in layout page

Tags: jquery, ajax, layout, asp.net-apicontroller

In my _Layout.cshtml, I have a menu that is static at the moment. Since the layout is not a view itself, I cannot use net core to make this menu dynamic. Therefore I wrote an api controller hoping to populate the menu using ajax.
Since I am completely novice to using Ajax and jquery my attempt is failing miserable.
So here is my code:
Controller:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
        public DataController(ApplicationDbContext dc)
        {
            dbContext = dc;
        }

        [HttpGet("Categories")]
        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var l = dbContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
            return l;
        }
    }
```

the html section of the menu in the Layout page, I want to update:

```
<ul id="menuCategories"class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mountains</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

And my scripts section in the layout page (with my ajax attempt):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="~/lib/js/assets/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>



    <script>
        $(document.ready(
            function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "api/Data/Categories",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {AddCategoriesTomenu(data)}

                })

            }
        ));

        var AddCategoriesTomenu = function (categories) {

            for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                $("menuCategories").append("<li><a href='#'>" + categories[i].Name + "</a></li>");


            }
        }
    </script>
```

Please bear my ignorance, and I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

In success method of ajax you can make it like this

```
$(document.ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "api/Data/Categories",
                contentType: "application/json",
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                var ul="";
               $.each(data, function (i, cat) {
               ul+= "<li><a href='#'>"+cat.Name+"</a> </li>";
                });
             $("#menuCategories").html('');
             $("#menuCategories").html(ul);                    }
            })

        }
    ));
```

Comment: I tried your code but it does not hit the controller, as also in my case. I have verified that the controller is working at the address:api/Data/Categories, so the problem must lie in the ajax code

Comment: I tried also:
$(document.ready(function () {
            alert("ok");
And I do not get the message

Comment: I managed to make the code work using: window.onload = function (), but the items (categories) are all undefined

Comment: Using the console I found the problem. The categories are all there but their property names have been decapitalized, that is property Name has become name. Why does this happen? Is it an effect of json?

Comment: Yes that might be, but I am not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/Data/Categories",
                contentType: "application/json",
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                var ul="";
               $.each(data, function (i, cat) {
               ul+= "<li><a href='#'>"+cat.Name+"</a> </li>";
                });
             $("#menuID").html('');
             $("#menuID").html(ul);                    }
            })

        }
    )();
```